# Extract a string of words between two specific words in R

Tags: regex, r

I have the following string : `"PRODUCT colgate good but not goodOKAY"`

I want to extract all the words between `PRODUCT` and `OKAY`

Answer (score 39):

This can be done with `sub`:

```
s <- "PRODUCT colgate good but not goodOKAY"
sub(".*PRODUCT *(.*?) *OKAY.*", "\\1", s)
```

giving:

```
[1] "colgate good but not good"
```

No packages are needed.

Here is a visualization of the regular expression:

```
.*PRODUCT *(.*?) *OKAY.*
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/J6Lw6EW4bcQH-BjW)

Comment: @g-grothendieck What I could if I wanted to extract the words between "colgate good" and "good"??? I'd expected " but not ", instead it returns "" if i change 'PRODUCT ' and 'OKAY' values straightfoward to 'colgate good' and 'good'.

Answer (score 24):

```
x = "PRODUCT colgate good but not goodOKAY"
library(stringr)
str_extract(string = x, pattern = "(?<=PRODUCT).*(?=OKAY)")
```

`(?<=PRODUCT)` -- look behind the match for `PRODUCT`

`.*` match everything except new lines.

`(?=OKAY)` -- look ahead to match `OKAY`.

I should add you don't need the `stringr` package for this, the base functions `sub` and `gsub` work fine. I use stringr for it's consistency of syntax: whether I'm extracting, replacing, detecting etc. the function names are predictable and understandable, and the arguments are in a consistent order. I use `stringr` because it saves me from needing the documentation every time.

(Note that for `stringr` versions less than 1.1.0, you need to specify perl-flavored regex to get lookahead and lookbehind functionality - so the pattern above would need to be wrapped in `perl()`.)

Comment: this doesn't work for me: 'could not find function "perl" ' not sure if a package is missing or something

Comment: @SimonC. the `stringr` package updated a bit ago to no longer need or use the `perl` function, so they removed it from the package. I just removed from the answer too so it works with the current version of `stringr`.

Answer (score 17):

You can use `gsub`:

```
vec <- "PRODUCT colgate good but not goodOKAY"

gsub(".*PRODUCT\\s*|OKAY.*", "", vec)
# [1] "colgate good but not good"
```

Answer (score 13):

You could use the `rm_between` function from the **qdapRegex** package.  It takes a string and a left and right boundary as follows:

```
x <- "PRODUCT colgate good but not goodOKAY"

library(qdapRegex)
rm_between(x, "PRODUCT", "OKAY", extract=TRUE)

## [[1]]
## [1] "colgate good but not good"
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use the package *unglue* :

```r
library(unglue)
x <- "PRODUCT colgate good but not goodOKAY"
unglue_vec(x, "PRODUCT {out}OKAY")
#> [1] "colgate good but not good"
```