# How to extract text in a range?

Tags: r, regex

I have for example:

```
Text=‘ Text1. Text2(Gino).Text(Ant)text. Text4. Text(Fi).’
```

Desired output:

```
Text=‘Text2(Gino). Text(Ant)text. Text(Fi)’
```

Comment: what is the pattern?

Comment: Please explain the logic behind this replacement.  It is not clear to me.

Comment: You can use  str_extract form stringr package or gsub in order to achieve so.It will fulfill all your requirements.

Comment: Reference :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28267400/extract-a-string-of-words-between-two-specific-words-in-r

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30912199/extract-letters-from-a-string-in-r

Answer (score 1):

You seem to only want the parts of the text that has parentheses, and the parts are delimited by dots.

Try this regex:

```
\w+\(\w+\)\w*\.\s*
```

Finding all the matches and joining all of them will produce the string you desire.

Explanation:

The regex matches some word characters (`\w+`), followed by an open parenthesis `\(` and some more word characters (`\w+`) followed by a closing parenthesis `\)`, and optionally followed by some more word characters (`\w*`). After that it looks for a dot and optional whitespace characters.

Comment: Might need to escape with double slashes(not sure though) but it seems to be the case in R.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you were looking for:

```
Text <- "Text1. Text2(Gino).Text(Ant)text. Text4. Text(Fi)."
Text <- gsub("Text1. ", "", Text, fixed=TRUE)
Text <- gsub("Text4. ", "", Text, fixed=TRUE)
Text
[1] "Text2(Gino).Text(Ant)text. Text(Fi)."
```

Changed `fixed=TRUE` to `fixed=FALSE` if you want to use regular expressions.

Comment: This assumes that the OP wants to explictly remove the text `Text1.`, which I doubt.

Comment: I proposed an edit to the question to explicitly reference regex for consistency with the tag.